# Ajax mostrar informacion dependiendo de un option select

Tags: php, ajax

> teacher.php

```
<?php
  include('php/conexion.php');

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $grupo = $_POST['grupo'];
    $getNotas = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM notas WHERE grupo='$grupo'") or die ('error al obtener datos de grupos');
  }

  $login=1;
  $getNotas="";

  $getDocente = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM docentes WHERE ID='$login'") or die ('error al obtener datos de alumno');
  $getGrupo = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM grupos WHERE docente='$login'") or die ('error al obtener datos de grupos');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html> .....

//Donde se muestra la lista de grupos.
<div class="container" id="evaluacion" style="display:none;">
    <div class="tipo-apilados" style="width:300px; height:140px; border-radius:3px;">
      <label class="aviso_usuario">Para iniciar la evaluación selecciona los siguientes datos:</label>
      <label class="info_texto">Seleccion un grupo</label>
      <select name="grupos" class="editText" id="grupo_evaluar">
         <option selected value="0">Mis grupos</option>
    <?php
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($getGrupo,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      echo "<option value='".$row['ID']."'>".$row['nombre']."</option>";
    ?>
      </select>
      <button  id="d_evaluacion" type="button" name="button" class="botonGuardar">Iniciar evaluación</button>
    </div>

<!--Tabla de notas de alumnos-->
    <?php
    if (!empty($grupo)){
          //Creamos tabla
          $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($getNotas);
          echo "
          <div class='tipo-apilados' style='width:700px; height:auto; border-radius:3px; display:none;' id='info_evaluacion'>
            <label class='aviso_usuario'>Modificar calificación de los estudiantes</label>
            <label style='padding:3px; border-radius:3px; color:#555; background-color:#EEE; font-size:13px;'>".$row_cnt." Alumnos registrados</label>

            <input type='text' name='' value='' placeholder='Buscar alumno por nombre' class='editText'>
            <table style='width:100%; margin-top:5px;'>
              <tr>
                <th style='width:150px;'>Alumno</th>
                <th style='width:10px; font-size:12px; background-color:#FFF;'>Final</th>
                <th style='width:20px; font-size:12px; background-color:#FFF;'>Unidad 1</th>
                <th style='width:20px; font-size:12px; background-color:#FFF;'>Unidad 2</th>
                <th style='width:20px; font-size:12px; background-color:#FFF;'>Unidad 3</th>
                <th style='width:20px; font-size:12px; background-color:#FFF;'>Unidad 4</th>
                <th style='width:20px; font-size:12px; background-color:#FFF;'>Opciones</th>
              </tr>
              ";
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getNotas,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
               {
                echo "
                <tr>
                  <td>".$row['alumno']."</td>
                  <td>".$row['promedio']."</td>
                  <td>".$row['unidad_1']."</td>
                  <td>".$row['unidad_2']."</td>
                  <td>".$row['unidad_3']."</td>
                  <td>".$row['unidad_4']."</td>
                  <td><button type='button' name='button' class='botonNormal' style='padding:2px; font-size:12px; width:90%;'>Editar</button></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                ";
              }
        }
     ?>
```

> Jquery al presionar el boton

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#d_evaluacion").click(function(){
    $seleccion = $('#grupo_evaluar option:selected').html();
    if ($seleccion == "Mis grupos") {
          $("#mensaje_error").fadeIn();
          $("#mensaje_error").html("Debe seleccionar un grupo a evaluar");
          $("#mensaje_error").delay(1000).fadeOut();
        } else {
        $("#info_evaluacion").slideDown();
        $.ajax({url:'/ingles/teacher.php',method:'post',data:{"grupo":"1"}});
      }
  });

});
```

No me muestra nada, es decir al parecer al enviar la informacion por ajax, se puede ver que mando un "1" es el codigo de un grupo, el teacher.php no resive nada.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el HTML donde se encuentra tu `select`? En la petición Ajax no estás manejando la respuesta del servidor... debes usar `done` para una respuesta exitosa, o `fail` para una respuesta fallida.

Comment: ya lo he intentado poner el done pero tampoco.

Comment: Me refería al **código HTML**, no a  una imagen, la cual no sirve para nada en este caso. En tu HTML debes tener algún elemento con este id: `d_evaluacion`... y prueba la petición Ajax de esta manera: `$.ajax({url:'index.php',method:'post',data:{"grupo":"1"}}).done(function(respuesta) {
  alert(respuesta);}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {alert( "error" + textStatus);
  });`

Comment: si d_evaluacion es solo un boton, puse tu codigo y aun así no me busca, me aparece igual.

Comment: ¿Puedes editar la pregunta colocando el HTML por favor, el código, no una imagen? ¿Tienes agregada la librería jQuery en el HTML?

Comment: es demaciado html, lo unico que quiero es un comboBox dinamico, que al seleccionar uno busque en la base de datos y muestre en la tabla, todo es funciona bien si en el WHERE grupo=1 de forma directa.

Comment: No tienes que poner todo el HTML, pon los encabezados del mismo, la parte del `<header>`  y la parte donde se encuentra tu botón. El código puede estar fallando porque no tienes la librería jQuery incorporada, o porque el botón no tiene el id que estás escuchando en jQuery.

Comment: ya añadi el codigo modificado, revisalo espero puedas ayudarme.

Comment: Si no tienes nada parecido a esto en el HTML, debes ponérselo, en la parte de arriba, antes de la etiqueta `<body>` del mismo: **`<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"</script>`**

Comment: todo eso si lo tengo, no lo agregue para acortar codigo, el problema no es con jquery, eso funciona bien, el problema es al resivir parametros.

Comment: Corrige el código como te dije antes: `$.ajax({url:'index.php',method:'post',data:{"grupo":"1"}}).d‌​one(function(respues‌​ta) { alert(respuesta);}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {alert( "error" + textStatus); });` y haz la prueba. No lo tienes así. De ese modo, como lo tienes ahora, nunca verás los resultados. Corrige y comenta lo que ocurre. De todos modos, edita la pregunta agregando, además de lo que ya pusiste,  sólo la línea donde agregas la biblioteca jQuery, de ese modo podrá hacer una revisión general de los elementos implicados.

Comment: me marcar error de sintaxis al parecer no escribiste bien el codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa los puntos indicados aquí y prueba.

Si da error, por favor comenta qué tipo de error te está dando.

Antes de proceder a lo que te indico, verifica que tienes tu asunto organizado como indico en la **NOTA**, al final de la respuesta. Si tienes duda sobre lo que digo, comenta...

Si te queda claro lo que digo en la nota, entonces procede:

1. Agrega la biblioteca jQuery en la sección `<head>` del HTML si no la tienes:

   ```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
   ```
2. En el HTML agrega un elemento `div` para ver la respuesta obtenida del servidor:

   ```
   <div id="result"></div>
   ```
3. Agrega los métodos que manejen las respuestas de la petición Ajax (done,fail).

   ```
   $(function() {

       $("#d_evaluacion").click(function(){

           /*Aquí el código jQuery que quieras*/
           /*Me centraré en la petición Ajax*/
           var request = $.ajax({
               url: 'index.php',
               method: 'post',
               data: {"grupo":"1"},
               dataType: "html"
           });

           request.done(function(response) {
               console.log(response);
               $("#result").html(response);            
           });

           request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
               alert("Hubo un error: " + textStatus);
           });

       });
   });
   ```

---

**NOTA:** En la pregunta no aparece planteado con claridad cómo están los archivos. Para que funcione:

- a. El código indicado en esta respuesta debe estar en el archivo que hace la llamada a Ajax. En ese archivo es donde está el botón con id=`d_evaluacion` el cual al presionarlo invoca la llamada Ajax.
- b. El código PHP que trae los datos del servidor debe estar en un archivo llamado `index.php` en la misma carpeta del archivo indicado en `(a)`.  Y debe devolver texto HTML con la respuesta del servidor.

Pongo esta nota porque no indicas en la pregunta que tengas las cosas organizadas de esa manera.